# Visual Studio Code Spring Boot Reload Static Content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to like using visual studio code for my spring boot projects.
But the problem is whenever I change the static files like js and CSS, I must stop and start the project. Previously when I using STS / Eclipse as my IDE, I don't have problem reloading the static contents (I just refresh my browser). 
Is there any way I can achieve the auto reload static content for my Java Spring Boot Project in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 4):

I'm probably a little late, but I had the same issue and the answer depends on what are you using, Maven, Gradle or something else.

I'm using Gradle 5.3 and to resolve this issue I added this line into `gradle.build` file:

```
bootRun { sourceResources sourceSets.main }
```

Also I installed  [spring-boot-devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), it provides automatic server restart feature which is very useful when you edit the code.

For building and running an application during development I use two terminals:

- First is for continuous build `gradle bootJar --continuous`
- Second is for launch an application `gradle bootRun`

Comment: Sorry I'm late to comment, My spring-boot project use maven and I also use the spring-boot-devtools, but still the same I must Ctrl+C (Restart the project)

Answer (score 0):

Suuuper late but I managed to get it working by installing [live reload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) on both my VS Code and browser and ensuring it was enabled by the output:

```
2020-01-16 11:47:16.079  INFO 2148 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
```

On the console when running my project and by clicking the extension icon on my browser with the tab of the project active, this enabled live reload when editing static content for me